# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python

I know that this topic has been dealt with many times already, and I have read all the answers and it seems that I did it right. but I don't understand what is wrong.

python_project:

```
Chronos
├── extractionScripts
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── peps.py
└── helperfunctions
    ├── __init__.py
    └── generallHelper.py
    └── pos.py
    └── logging.py
```

I have two folders (extractionScripts and helperFunctions).

when I try to import modules from the helperFunctions into the peps.py , I get the error -
from helperFunctions.invoiceHeader import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helperFunctions'

peps.py

```
import re
import sys
print (sys.path) 

from helperFunctions.generallHelper import *
from helperFunctions.pos import *
from helperFunctions.logging import *
```

print (sys.path)  shows

```
['C:\\Users\\djoni\\Desktop\\Sixt\\Chronos\\extractionScripts', 'C:\\Users\\djoni\\Desktop\\Sixt\\Chronos\\helperFunctions', 'C:\\Users\\djoni\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Users\\djoni\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\djoni\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\djoni\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310', 'C:\\Users\\djoni\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages']
```

in other topics they wrote that there should be an *init* file, or the path should be added to the sys file, but I have them.

Comment: try putting an empty ```__init__.py``` in Chronos as well and then do ```from .helperFunctions```

Comment: it's there, I already deleted it and added it again

Comment: the question doesn't show one in Chronos? are the ```__init__.py``` files empty?

Comment: Yes, he is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import any module in Python , Python search in the `sys.path` list that has all modules
have a look in your `sys.path` you won't see the `Chronos` File so in the file you try to import in it put this

```py
import sys 
from pathlib import Path 
path_to_Chronos = Path(__file__).parent.parent
print(path_to_Chronos ) # Check this Right 
sys.path.append(path_to_Chronos)
# then import and you will find it works
```

Answer (score 0):

Pro Check your names
this is how you want to import it

```py
from helperFunctions.generallHelper import *
from helperFunctions.pos import *
from helperFunctions.logging import *
```

but Do you see how you name it

```
└── helperfunctions
    ├── __init__.py
    └── generallHelper.py
    └── pos.py
    └── logging.py
```

`F` it is the Problem ...

Comment: oh, sorry,this is my typo here. I have the same file and folder names with F

Comment: Try to add ```__init__.py ``` to the main file and then .... append the path of it in the ``` sys.path.append(PATH_TO_MAIN)```

Comment: Chronos is the main file ...Check if it works!

Comment: I have  __init__.py  in Chronos

Comment: okay ... add it to the python path

Comment: Ok, restarted vsc and it worked!!
Thanks.

Comment: I explain in another answer how the importing work please see it , you will understand good things